# Ruby on Rails security vulnerability with user enumeration via id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

With Ruby on Rails, my models are being created with increasing unique ids. For example, the first user has a user id of 1, the second 2, the third 3.

This is not good from a security perspective because if someone can snoop on the user id of the last created user (perhaps by creating a new user), they can infer your growth rate.  They can also easily guess user ids.

Is there a good way to use random ids instead?

What have people done about this? Google search doesn't reveal much of anything.

Comment: I'm lost as to why this is a security vulnerability...

Comment: Inferring growth rate has nothing to do with security.

Comment: Not really a vulnerability as it doesn't allow the user to compromise your application in any way. Stackoverflow seems to use even incremental user ids.

Comment: Credential enumeration is only a problem for the *login string*.  We don't log in to StackOverflow with our numerical IDs so they are not sensitive in that way.  Growth rate can be sensitive financially as an indication of how well the business is doing.  Of course, if it's doing well you usually want this information to be public.

Comment: With some careful thinking of potential issues, you can improve on this: in a `before_save` filter in the model, set the `self.id` to a random number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not consider exposing user IDs to public as a security flaw, there should be other mechanisms for security. Maybe it is a "marketing security flaw" when visitors find out you do not have that million users they promise ;-)

Anyway:

To avoid IDs in urls at all you can use the user's login in all places. Make sure the login does not contain some special characters (`./\#?` etc.), that cause problems in routes (use a whitelist regex). Also login names may not be changed later, that can cause trouble if you have hard links/search engine entries to your pages.

Example calls are `/users/Jeff` and `/users/Jeff/edit` instead of `/users/522047` and `/users/522047/edit`.

In your user class you need to override the `to_param` to use the login for routes instead of the user's id. This way there is no need to replace anything in your routes file nor in helpers like `link_to @user`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    self.login
  end
end
```

Then in every controller replace `User.find` by `User.find_by_login`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show 
     @user = User.find_by_login(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Or use a `before_filter` to replace the params before. For other controllers with nested resources use `params[:user_id]`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :get_id_from_login

  def show 
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private 
  # As users are not called by +id+ but by +login+ here is a function
  # that converts a params[:id] containing an alphanumeric login to a 
  # params[:id] with a numeric id
  def get_id_from_login
    user = User.find_by_login(params[:id])
    params[:id] = user.id unless user.nil?
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you would generate random INTEGER id it also can be compromted very easy. You should generate a random token for each user like MD5 or SHA1 ("asd342gdfg4534dfgdf"), then it would help you. And you should link to user profile with this random hash.

Note, this is not actually the **hash** concept, it just a random string.

Another way is to link to user with their nick, for example.

However, my guess is knowing the users ID or users count or users growth rate is not a vulnerability itself!

Answer (score 0):

Add a field called `random_id` or whatever you want to your User model.  Then when creating a user, place this code in your UsersController:

```
def create
  ...
  user.random_id = User.generate_random_id
  user.save
end
```

And place this code in your User class:

```
# random_id will contain capital letters and numbers only
def self.generate_random_id(size = 8)
  alphanumerics = ('0'..'9').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a
  key = (0..size).map {alphanumerics[Kernel.rand(36)]}.join

  # if random_id exists in database, regenerate key
  key = generate_random_id(size) if User.find_by_random_id(key)

  # output the key
  return key
end
```

If you need lowercase letters too, add them to alphanumerics and make sure you get the correct random number from the kernel, i.e. `Kernel.rand(62)`.

Also be sure to modify your routes and other controllers to utilize the `random_id` instead of the default `id`.

Comment: Why not just set the `id` itself to a random number? That way, you do not need to change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a proper authorization layer to prevent un-authorized access.

Let us say you you display the user information in `show` action of the `Users` controller and the code is as shown below:

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :require_user

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

This implementation is vulnerable to id guessing. You can easily fix it by ensuring that show action always shows the information of the logged in user:

```
def show
  @user = current_user
end
```

Now regardless of what id is given in the URL you will display the current users profile.

Let us say that we want to allow account admin and account owner to access the show action:

```
def show
  @user = current_user.has_role?(:admin) ? User.find(params[:id]) : current_user
end
```

OTH authorization logic is better implemented using a gem like [CanCan](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGEQFjAA&url=https://github.com/ryanb/cancan&ei=HLriT9qYI6PY2gXz9vi9Cw&usg=AFQjCNHOGf1FuQRmMgIqArmb2ALmGmt6cQ&sig2=WzPx78NxOzJAHHn7Np_1tw).